# Monitor the time between mouse events with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an image for which I would like to monitor 3 events:

1. **onmousedown**
2. **onmouseup**
3. **onmouseout**

Basically, I have to control the time passed between the onmousedown and onmouseup events:

```
<img id="protoImage" src="/path/to/img.png" onmousedown="tsMouseDown()" onmouseup="tsMouseUp()" onmouseout="tsMouseOut()" ondragstart='return false;'/>
```

If I maintain the button clicked more than 500 ms I should execute a task, otherwise another.

This is the Javascript code I wrote:

```
var lastTime = 0;
var now = 0;
var tmptimer = 0;
var loopFlag = false;
var timeFlag = false;

function tsMouseDown()
{
  loopFlag = true;
  timeFlag = false;

  var div = document.getElementById("debugDiv");
  div.textContent = "tsMouseDown...";

  lastTime = new Date().getTime();
  var tmptimer = lastTime;

  while((loopFlag == true) && ((tmptimer - lastTime) <= 500))
  {
    tmptimer = new Date().getTime();
  }

  if((tmptimer - lastTime) >= 500)
  {
    timeFlag = true;
    div.textContent = "tsMouseDown ... 500 ms passed";
  }
}

function tsMouseUp()
{
  loopFlag = false;
  var div = document.getElementById("debugDiv");

  now = new Date().getTime();

  if(timeFlag == false)
    div.textContent = "tsMouseUp: " + (now - lastTime) + "< 500 ms";  
  else
    div.textContent = "tsMouseUp: " + (now - lastTime) + "> 500 ms";
}

function tsMouseOut()
{
  var div = document.getElementById("debugDiv");
  div.textContent = "tsMouseOut: 0";
}
```

But it seems the **while** loop is never interrupted, even if I release the mouse button, since the value of the time elapsed is always major than 500 ms..

I am confused and I don't know how to solve this problem, also because JavaScript is not my best...

How can I modify my code to solve this situation ? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might help

```
var timer;
function tsMouseDown()
{
    timer = setTimeout( function(){
        div.textContent = "tsMouseDown ... 500 ms passed";
    }, 500 );
}
function tsMouseUp()
{
    clearTimeout( timer );
}
```